# Setting requirepass with args while deploying Redis in k8s works with $() but not with ${}

Tags: docker, kubernetes, redis, sh, kubernetes-helm

I am trying to deploy Redis (by creating a Helm chart) as a StatefulSet in Kubernetes cluster. I am not creating another Redis image on top of Official Redis Docker image, rather I am just trying to use the defaults available in [Official Redis Docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/redis/) and just provide my `redis.conf` and `requirepass` at runtime.

To provide `redis.conf`, I am using a ConfigMap and mounting it in `/config/redis.conf` in the container.

Now, I want to pass `--requirepass` option as `args` in Kubernetes as below:

```
...
containers: [
  {
    name: redis,
    image: {
      repository: redis,
      tag: 5.0
    },
    imagePullPolicy: Always,
    workingDir: /data/,
    args: [ "/config/redis.conf", "--requirepass", "<password>" ],  # line of concern
    ports: [
      containerPort: 6379
    ],
    env: [
      {
        name: REDIS_AUTH,
        valueFrom: {
          secretKeyRef: {
            name: redis,
            key: password
          }
        }
      }
    ],
...
```

The following line fails:

```
args: [ "/config/redis.conf", "--requirepass", "${REDIS_AUTH}" ]
```

and on the contrary, this works:

```
args: [ "/config/redis.conf", "--requirepass", "$(REDIS_AUTH)" ]
```

Even though, `$()` syntax is for command substitution and `REDIS_AUTH` is an environment variable rather than an executable, how does it work and `${REDIS_AUTH}` does not?

Comment: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/57726

Comment: @Adiii Thanks for the link but `HOSTNAME` is an actual command and in my case, `REDIS_AUTH` isn't an actual command. Even then its working. I don't understand how its working.

Answer (score 4):

This is a Kubernetes specific feature that if you want to expand an environment variable in `command` or `args` field then you've to use the `$()` syntax instead of `${}` syntax.

Check this link: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-command-argument-container/#use-environment-variables-to-define-arguments